# Nested Alamofire Request and Async Dispatch Queue

Tags: swift, api, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I am trying to implement a nested Alamofire request :
- The first request call a code 
- The second request call a result using the code obtained in the first request

Moreover, I guess there is a problem with the DispatchQueue object, I was thinking to use DispatchQueue.main.async for the second request but this is not accepted here.

In the lines below, the second request returns me a nil result because it does not incorporate the code found in the first request.

```
    func fetch(jan: String) {

 AF.request("https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemSearch?appid=\(appId)&jan=\(jan)&hits=50").responseDecodable(of: Welcome.self , queue: DispatchQueue.main) { response in 
    let boncode1 = String("\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the0?.code)")     
    print(boncode1)

AF.request("https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemLookup?appid=\(self.appId)&itemcode=\(boncode1)").responseDecodable(of: troisViewController.Welcome.self , queue: DispatchQueue.main) { response in

            print("\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the0?.name ?? "is nil" )")

        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone already dealt with a similar issue,

Thank you in advance

Comment: The `queue:` parameter receives a DispatchQueue object, whereas `DispatchQueue.main.async` is a method that returns nothing. The completion handler always returns asynchronously so I don't think you should worry about this. What you can do is creating a custom DispatchQueue and pass it instead of DispatchQueue.main. ie:
`DispatchQueue(label: "com.your-domain.request-thread", qos: .utility)`

Comment: Regarding the 2nd request that returns nil, without running the code it's hard to tell whether it's an issue with the calls you make to the API, or on the Swift side. For instance is `boncode1` assigned to the value you expect? It seems to be correctly interpolated in the 2nd request.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you need 2 service calls, then nested functions might fit your needs.
But imagine you need to process a result of 5 or even more service calls, it will be [Pyramid of Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)) nightmare for sure.

To avoid it I would recommend you take a look at [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) API and learn how to utilize it.

> Groups allow you to aggregate a set of tasks and synchronize behaviors on the group. You attach multiple work items to a group and schedule them for asynchronous execution on the same queue or different queues. When all work items finish executing, the group executes its completion handler. You can also wait synchronously for all tasks in the group to finish executing.

So you can implement your function like this:

```swift
func fetch(jan: String) {

    // Local variable
    var boncode1: String = ""

    // Create group
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    // Fetch data from the first service

    let url_1 = "https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemSearch?appid=\(appId)&jan=\(jan)&hits=50"

    // Indicate that the first block of work (first service call) has entered the group.
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    AF.request(url_1).responseDecodable(of: Welcome.self) { response in
        // Store data in local variable
        boncode1 = String("\(response.value?.resultSet.the0.result.the0?.code)")

        // Indicate that the first block in the group finished executing.
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    // Fetch data from the second service

    let url_2 = "https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemLookup?appid=\(self.appId)&itemcode=\(boncode1)"

    //Indicate that the second block of work (second service call) has entered the group.
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    AF.request(url_2).responseDecodable(of: troisViewController.Welcome.self) { response in
        // handle response from the second service if you need it

        // Indicate that the second block in the group finished executing.
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    // This function schedules a notification block to be submitted to the specified queue 
    // when all blocks associated with the dispatch group have completed.
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        // process results of 2 service calls
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I opted for the first option which seems to perform well with a simple "if else". It wasn't successful with the Dispatch Group Method unfortunatelly. As it is two different API calls, I hope that the "if else" method will not reduce the performance of the data extraction in terms of speed.

Comment: Okay so if we have two or more async calls, we dont need to have "dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) " blocks everytime we leave a dispatch group?

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire provides no async primitives of its own. Rather, you can compose Alamofire's requests with existing primitives or provide your own. The simplest, if inelegant, solution here is merely to nest the calls:

```swift
AF.request(...).responseDecodable(of: ...) { outer in
    // Handle outer response.
    AF.request(...).responseDecodable(of: ...) { inner in
        // Handle inner response.
    }
}
```

Additionally, there's no need to pass `DispatchQueue.main` to Alamofire, as that's the default queue your response handlers are called on anyway.